# How to Change Ramdisk Size without Restarting

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ramdisk

I have the following line on my fstab file:

```
ramdisk /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,size=2048m
```

Now I want to increase the size to 4096m.

What I did is change it to:

```
ramdisk /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,size=4096m
```

and issue the command:

```
mount -a
```

but when I check it if it change using df -h, the value is still the same at 2gb.

Anyone know how to change it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typing `mount -o remount,size=4096m /tmp` should do the trick.

Comment: BTW, I have the following line in mtab file: `ramdisk /tmp tmpfs rw,mode=1777,size=4096m,size=4096m 0 0`. There are two `size=4096m`. Is this okay?

Comment: @jaYPabs I don't think that is going to be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. I run your code again with size as `mount -o remount /tmp` and it works great. No double entry in mtab file.

Comment: Unless you want to override the fstab entry it's not necessary to specify the size on the command line.